# How to remove the signin page from the report when Power BI report is embedded into Web Application using Secure Embed Option

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a web application in which Azure Active Directory authentication is implemented.

Now I am embedded my Power BI reports in this Web Application using Secure Embed Option.

Whenever a user logs into the web application, he sees a separate sign in button on the Power BI reports after successful login into Web Application.

Is there a way to automatically signin into Power BI reports using the currently logged in user.

Currently logged in user has access to both Azure AD as well as Power BI.

Comment: Are you using a master account for embedding? Do your workspaces use a dedicated capacity?

Comment: I think that for this you need to use powerBI embedded, you can use the _auth token_ that the authentication in the active directory gives you for generate an _embed token_ and retrive the report with the rest api for powerBi embedded

Answer (score 2):

Secure embed option is used to embed a report in a given iframe where every user would need to sign-in within the iframe.

> In order to provide a single sign-on experience, you would need to use the user login authentication to generate an access token.

**Generating access tokens -**

C# - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token

JS - (Using ADAL) https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

This access token can then be used to **embed reports within an HTML container** (for example, a div element) using the Power BI embedded JS library.

When the token is created as per the different users logging in, then such implementation is called as **'User Owns Data'**.

Sample code and summary - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization

Embed setup tool for user owns data: https://app.powerbi.com/embedsetup/UserOwnsData